# Mock ListUsersIterable from AWS SDK - JUnit

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, junit, amazon-cognito

In my service class method I have this block of code which I need to test

```
    List<UserType> users = new ArrayList<>();
    ListUsersIterable responses = cognitoclient.listUsersPaginator(ListUsersRequest
                                    .builder()
                                    .userPoolId(userUserPoolId)
                                    .build());
    for (ListUsersResponse response : responses) {
        users.addAll(response.users());
    }
```

While mocking `cognitoclient.listUsersPaginator()` I am not able to create a stub of **ListUsersIterable** as no setter methods are available.

Below are the AWS dependencies I am using

```
implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.0')
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:cognitoidentityprovider'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sts'
```

Comment: Mocking does not hit the actual AWS Service and therefore you will not get data back from the service.

Comment: @smac2020 I dont want to hit the actual AWS service as part of writing junit test case. I need to return the stub when the service get called by mocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
List<AttributeType> userAttributesList = new ArrayList<>();  
userAttributesList.add(AttributeType.builder().name("custom:status").value("active").build());

ListUsersIterable mockUsersIterable = mock(ListUsersIterable.class);        
when(cognitoclient.listUsersPaginator(any(ListUsersRequest.class))).thenReturn(mockUsersIterable);
List<ListUsersResponse> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<UserType> userTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
userTypeList.add(UserType.builder().attributes(userAttributesList).build());
list.add(ListUsersResponse.builder().users(userTypeList).build());
when(mockUsersIterable.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator());
```

Comment: How did you mock cognitoclient? I have problem with that

Comment: @JakubJakubowski In my Spring Service Class, under PostConstruct I am calling one method (let's name it method1) where I build CognitoIdentityProviderClient (CognitoClient) object and assign it to instance var. Under my Test class, I am mocking CognitoIdentityProviderClient under BeforeEach and passing it to method1.